# Python code for fetching data from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code.
And getting [].
Please help me find my mistake.

```
from urllib import urlopen
optionsUrl = 'http://www.moneycontrol.com/commodity/'
optionsPage = urlopen(optionsUrl)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(optionsPage)
print soup.findAll(text='MCX')
```

Comment: Your code returns things for me. Which version of BeautifulSoup do you have? I've seen weird behavior with some recent ones, now I'm on 3.2.1 and it seems better.

Comment: works fine here even with bs4 while using python 2.7

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup version 4.3.1. It is not showing any error. But I am getting only [] as output. It is showing expected results when I am using text=' '

Comment: What are you trying to scrape from the website actually?

Comment: My final aim to pick MCX commodity prices table. I am trying to use print soup.findAll(text='copper-price')[0].parent.parent. But it is not error.

Answer (score 2):

This will grab that list of commodities for you (tested on python 2.7). You need to isolate that commodity table then work your way down the rows, reading each row and extracting the data from each column

```
import urllib2
import bs4

# Page with commodities
URL = "http://www.moneycontrol.com/commodity/"

# Download the page data and create a BeautitulSoup object
commodityPage = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
commodityPageText = commodityPage.read()
commodityPageSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(commodityPageText)

# Extract the div with the commodities table and find all the table rows
commodityTable = commodityPageSoup.find_all("div", "equity com_ne")
commodittTableRows =  commodityTable[0].find_all("tr")

# Trim off the table header row
commodittTableRows = commodittTableRows[1:]

# Iterate over the table rows and print out the commodity name and price
for commodity in commodittTableRows:
    # Separate all the table columns
    columns = commodity.find_all("td")

    # -------------- Get the values from each column
    # ROW 1: Name and date
    nameAndDate = columns[0].text
    nameAndDate = nameAndDate.split('-')
    name = nameAndDate[0].strip()
    date = nameAndDate[1].strip()

    # ROW 2: Price
    price = float(columns[1].text)

    # ROW 3: Change
    change = columns[2].text.replace(',', '') # Remove commas from change value
    change = float(change)

    # ROW 4: Percentage change
    percentageChange = columns[3].text.replace('%', '') # Remove the percentage symbol
    percentageChange = float(percentageChange)

    # Print out the data
    print "%s on %s was %.2f - a change of %.2f (%.2f%%)" % (name, date, price, change, percentageChange)
```

Which gives the results

```
Gold on 5 Oct was 30068.00 - a change of 497.00 (1.68%)
Silver on 5 Dec was 50525.00 - a change of 1115.00 (2.26%)
Crudeoil on 19 Sep was 6924.00 - a change of 93.00 (1.36%)
Naturalgas on 25 Sep was 233.80 - a change of 0.30 (0.13%)
Aluminium on 30 Sep was 112.25 - a change of 0.55 (0.49%)
Copper on 29 Nov was 459.80 - a change of 3.40 (0.74%)
Nickel on 30 Sep was 882.20 - a change of 5.90 (0.67%)
Lead on 30 Sep was 131.80 - a change of 0.70 (0.53%)
Zinc on 30 Sep was 117.85 - a change of 0.75 (0.64%)
Menthaoil on 30 Sep was 871.90 - a change of 1.80 (0.21%)
Cotton on 31 Oct was 21350.00 - a change of 160.00 (0.76%)
```

Comment: Nice. Maybe put `%.2f` instead of just `%f` for the decimal places? (And Separate spelled wrong) I would edit but don't want to mess up your output example.

Comment: Thanks, I whacked this together pretty quickly hence the mistakes. Edited answer with those changes.